# image processing by Opencvjs

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to convert an image using prewitt method using javascript. When I run it I get this error:

> BindingError {name: 'BindingError', message: 'Cannot pass "array([[ 1, 1, 1],\n [ 0, 0, 0],\n       [-1,-1,-1]])" as a Mat', stack: 'BindingError: Cannot pass "array([[ 1, 1, 1],\n    …p://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:103232:9)'}

Error at Filter2D

```js
const prewitt=new cv.Mat()
const KERNEL_X=np.array([[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[-1,-1,-1]])
const KERNEL_Y=np.array([[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]])
let img_prewittx=cv.filter2D(img,prewitt,-1,KERNEL_X)
let img_prewitty=cv.filter2D(img,prewitt,-1,KERNEL_Y)
cv.imshow(this.prewittRef.current,img_prewittx,img_prewitty)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [good example](https://answers.opencv.org/question/224848/how-do-i-create-and-use-a-custom-kernel-with-cvfilter2d/) for using `cv.filter2D` by OpenCV.js.

- The type of the kernel argument should be `cv.Mat()` and not `np.array` (it's not Python where we can use np.array as OpenCV Mat).
- The destination matrix is stored in the second argument of `cv.filter2D` (it is not returned as in Python).
- It is recommended to apply the filter on Grayscale input (especially not on BGRA input, because the output alpha channel may be fully transparent).

Assume `gray` is the input image.
Apply `cv.filter2D` as follows:

```
const KERNEL_X = cv.matFromArray(3, 3, cv.CV_32FC1, [1,1,1, 0,0,0, -1,-1,-1]);
cv.filter2D(gray, img_prewittx, -1, KERNEL_X)
```

---

Complete code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello OpenCV.js</title>
</head>

<body>
<p id="status">OpenCV.js is loading...</p>
<div>
  <div class="inputoutput">
    <img id="imageSrc" alt="No Image" />
    <div class="caption">imageSrc <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="file" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputoutput">
    <canvas id="canvasOutput" ></canvas>
    <div class="caption">canvasOutput</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script async src="opencv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
let imgElement = document.getElementById('imageSrc');
let inputElement = document.getElementById('fileInput');
inputElement.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
}, false);

//Read image and execute the OpenCV code sample.
imgElement.onload = function () {
  let img = cv.imread(imgElement);
  let gray = new cv.Mat()
  let img_prewittx = new cv.Mat();
  let img_prewitty = new cv.Mat();

  if (img.channels() == 4)
  {
    cv.cvtColor(img, gray, cv.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY); //Convert from BGRA to Grayscale.
  }
  else if (img.channels() == 3)
  {
    cv.cvtColor(img, gray, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY); //Convert from BGR to Grayscale.
  }
  else
  {
    gray = img.clone();
  }

  //const prewitt = new cv.Mat()
  //const KERNEL_X = np.array([[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[-1,-1,-1]])
  //const KERNEL_Y = np.array([[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]])
  const KERNEL_X = cv.matFromArray(3, 3, cv.CV_32FC1, [1,1,1, 0,0,0, -1,-1,-1]);
  const KERNEL_Y = cv.matFromArray(3, 3, cv.CV_32FC1, [-1,0,1, -1,0,1, -1,0,1]);

  //https://answers.opencv.org/question/224848/how-do-i-create-and-use-a-custom-kernel-with-cvfilter2d/
  cv.filter2D(gray, img_prewittx, -1, KERNEL_X)
  cv.filter2D(gray, img_prewitty, -1, KERNEL_Y)

  cv.imshow('canvasOutput', img_prewittx); //Show img_prewittx for testing

  img.delete();
  gray.delete();
  img_prewittx.delete();
  img_prewitty.delete();
};


//check openCV
var Module = {
  // https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/module.html#Module.onRuntimeInitialized
  onRuntimeInitialized() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'OpenCV.js is ready.';
  }
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```